# CDI: Not proxyable third party class (no args constructor)

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I've created a producer in order to get an `OAuthTokenRequest`. It's a thrid party library class. The source code of this class is:

```
public class OAuthTokenRequest extends AbstractOAuthTokenRequest {

    public OAuthTokenRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws OAuthSystemException, OAuthProblemException {
        super(request);
    }
}
```

As you can see it has only one constructor with one parameter. So, when I'm trying to deploy my application I'm getting this error:

> OAuthTokenRequest is not proxyable because it has no no-args constructor

My producer is:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class OAuthTokenRequestRepositoryProducer {

    @Produces @RequestScoped
    public OAuthTokenRequest getOAuthTokenRequest(@Context HttpServletRequest httpRequest) throws OAuthSystemException, OAuthProblemException {
        return new OAuthTokenRequest(httpRequest);
    }
}
```

Each time a request is reached an `OAuthTokenRequest` should be built.
How could I solve it?

Comment: What does your producer look like? What scope are you trying to use?

Comment: I've edited the post.